# How to solve CORS issue in swagger-ui-express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swagger-ui

I'm getting "Possible cross-origin (CORS) issue?" error for Spec2 when run this swagger-ui-express app:

```
const express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');

var options = {
  explorer: true,
  swaggerOptions: {
    urls: [
      {
        url: 'http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json',
        name: 'Spec1'
      },
      {
        url: 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx/swagger.json',
        name: 'Spec2'
      }
    ]
  }
}

app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(null, options));

app.listen(8080, () => console.log(`Listening on port 8080!`))
```

Neither `app.use(cors())` nor `app.use(swaggerUi.cors())` helps. How can it be fixed?

Comment: did you checked this one, https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/cors/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is exact problem you are facing, but the following solution has fixed my issue.

I was using a fetch on an endpoint and the error suggested that the received request has an origin (header) of value null.

I have set up a request interceptor to add an origin header on the request. Example

```js
app.get("/docs", swaggerUi.setup(null, {
    swaggerOptions: {
        requestInterceptor: function(request){
            request.headers.Origin = `http://localhost:3000`;
            return request;
        },
        url: `http://localhost:3000/docs/api-doc`
    }
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

check the [link](https://github.com/APIDevTools/swagger-express-middleware/blob/master/docs/middleware/CORS.md) which gives the way to overcome the issue. Also, you can install CORS plugin in chrome if you want and try it.

Comment: Thank you Arun.. I saw that but cannot really get a clue how to use it with my options object rather than yaml file